# vsto for outlook and using wix to build it, i have sat the location of INSTALLFOLDER to programfiles , but in outlook it is comming as AppData/locals

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, wix, windows-installer

I've created a VSTO add-in for Outlook and built an installer using WiX. The installation works correctly, placing all files into the intended Program Files directory. However, certain firewalls are flagging the add-in's DLLs, detecting them in the AppData/Local folder.

Why does Outlook continue to load the add-in's DLLs from AppData/Local even when they're installed in Program Files?
How can I prevent Outlook from using the AppData/Local copies of the DLLs and ensure it uses the Program Files installation?